# Handling exception from webservices called by OpenFeign

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, openfeign

I have several microservices and I use openfeign to call the different micro services.
the entry point for the global application is named dispatcher-ws. His role is to dispatch calls depending on the payload.

As entry I do have the following payload:

```
{
   "operation": "signature",
   "clientId": "abcdef",
   ...
   "pdfDocument": "JVBERi0xLjMNCiXi48/TDQoNCjEg..."
}
```

I have microservice named signature-ws that handles pdf signature. So far, so good. I implemented my client this way:

```
@FeignClient(name="signature-ws", decode404 = true, url = "http://localhost:8080/signature-ws/api")
public interface SignatureClient {    
    @PostMapping("/signature")
    Map<String, Object> signDocument(RequestDto request) throws AppServiceException;
}
```

In my service layer, I try to make the call depending on operation value:

```
@Service
public class RequestServiceImpl implements DispatchService {
    private final RequestRepository requestRepository;
    private final SignatureClient signatureClient;
    private final Resilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory circuitBreakerFactory;


    @Autowired
    public DispatchServiceImpl(RequestRepository requestRepository,
                               SignatureClient signatureClient,
                               Resilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory circuitBreakerFactory) {
        this.requestRepository = requestRepository;
        this.signatureClient = signatureClient;
        this.circuitBreakerFactory = circuitBreakerFactory;
    }


@Override
public RequestDto handleRequest(RequestDto request) {
    RequestDto returnValue = new RequestDto();
    // if not initialized, throw null pointer exception...
    returnValue.setPayloads(new ArrayList<>());
    if(request.getOperation().equals("signature") {
       Resilience4JCircuitBreaker circuitBreaker = circuitBreakerFactory.create("signature");
       Supplier<Map<String, Object>> signatureResponseSupplier =
                    () -> signatureClient.signDocument(request);
       Map<String, Object> signatureResponse = circuitBreaker.run(
           signatureResponseSupplier,
           throwable -> handleException()
       );
      ...
      returnValue.getResponses().add(signatureResponse)
 
    }
    return retunValue;
}

...
private Map<String, Object> handleException() {
    Map<String, Object> returnValue = new HashMap<>();
    returnValue.put("Error", "Error rmessage ... ");
    returnValue.put("status", "Failure");
    return returnValue;
}
```

If i don't pass pdfDocument in signature webservice, I do retrieve an exception.

```
{
    "errorId": "Qe99DwntFrMPCAfuZfDQW1ucwNh5BK",
    "status": "ERROR",
    "operations": "signature",
    "profile": "client123456",
    "errorMessage": "PDF is missing",
    "createdAt": 1647354022127
}
```

I would like to retrieve the exception response and pass the key values to the map in the handleException method. At this stage, it doesn't return anything and worse of all, i do return a 200 status.

I implemented a controllerAdvice that manage the response to return. This class is identical in all my web services(i should think about creating a micro service for handling all exceptions...)

```
@ControllerAdvice(basePackages = { "com.company.app" })
public class AppExceptionsHandler {
    private final RequestContext requestContext;

    @Autowired
    public AppExceptionsHandler(RequestContext requestContext) {
        this.requestContext = requestContext;
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(value = {AppServiceException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleAppException(AppServiceException ex,
                                                             WebRequest request) {
        // récupérer le body
        DispatchDto response = requestContext.getResponse();
        ErrorMessage errorMessage = ErrorMessage.builder()
                .errorId(response.getId())
                .status(RequestOperationStatus.ERROR.name())
                .operations(response.getOperations())
                .profile(response.getProfile())
                .errorMessage(ex.getMessage())
                .createdAt(new Date())
                .build();
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorMessage, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

What i expect is to return the same exception in my dispatcher microservice.

Answer (score 0):

I found a trick to solve this issue.
First I surrounded with a try catch my feign request :

```
try {
    ...
    Map<String, Object> facturxResponse = 
           facturXClient.createFacturX(dispatchDto);
        ...
} catch(FeignException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    throw new AppServiceException(e.getMessage());
}
```

I noted that e.getMessage returns a string which has this pattern:

```
[500 Internal Server Error] during [POST] to [http://localhost:8080/my-ws/api/ws] 
[FacturXClient#createFacturX(DispatchDto)]: [{"errorId":"z3o1bE8SJrm8WGrxlpIIWe6TNf0NzR","status":"ERROR","operations":"facturx","profile":"client123456","errorMessage":"PDF is missing","createdAt":1647422337344}]
```

I throw this exception and intercept the response

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = {AppServiceException.class})
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleUserServiceException(AppServiceException ex,
                                                         WebRequest request) throws JsonProcessingException {
    String input = ex.getMessage();
    String[] splitResponse = input.split(":", 4);
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
    String response = splitResponse[3].trim().substring(1, splitResponse[3].trim().length() -1);
    ErrorMessage errorMessage = mapper.readValue(response, ErrorMessage.class);
    System.out.println(errorMessage.toString());

    return new ResponseEntity<>(errorMessage, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}
```

I finally get the expected response:

```
{
    "errorId": "z3o1bE8SJrm8WGrxlpIIWe6TNf0NzR",
    "status": "ERROR",
    "operations": "facturx",
    "profile": "client123456",
    "errorMessage": "PDF is missing",
    "createdAt": "2022-03-16T09:18:57.344+00:00"
}
```